# Finding the difference between lists in R: getting the values as opposed to Boolean or list position

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out how to get a list of the values that differ between two lists of values of unequal length in R.

I have tried the following using a negated version of %in%:

```
list1 <- c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11)
list2 <- c(1, 3, 7, 11)
'%ni%' <- Negate('%in%')
outlist <- list1 %ni% list2
outlist
outlisttrue <- which(outlist==TRUE)
outlisttrue
```

Which returns the following:

```
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[1] 3 5
```

So `outlist` gives me the data in a Boolean fashion, and `outlisttrue` seems to be giving the positions in the list for the `TRUE` results.

What I would like returned is the following, the list of actual values that differ between the two original lists:

```
[1] 5 9
```

Can anyone offer a simple solution for how I might modify my approach here? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
setdiff(list1, list2)
# [1] 5 9
```

or

```
list1[list1 %ni% list2]
#[1] 5 9
```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple! Thank you for that.

Comment: @PatrickT that sounds strange. i..e `df <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = 2:6); setdiff(df$col1, df$col2)#
[1] 1`  If you can show a smalll reproducible example, can test it

Comment: @PatrickT your first case is a vector set diff i.e. `setdiff(df$col1, df$col2)` and the second is  a list with each element list member `setdiff(as.list(df$col1), as.list(df$col2))#
[[1]]
[1] 1` whereas the other cas is a `list` of length 1 vs list of length 1 `setdiff(list(df$col1), list(df$col2))
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5`

Comment: @PatrickT methods for `setdiff` includes the default option and a data.frame option.  So you can use `setdiff(data.frame(col1 = 1:5), data.frame(col1 = 1:3))
  col1
1    4
2    5` and not a `list`

Comment: @PatrickT i.e. According to `?setdiff` -`Performs set union, intersection, (asymmetric!) difference, equality and membership on two vectors.`  Using the function on an input object that is not the preferrred will have unexpected results

Comment: Thanks akrun! You're right, it's working fine. I must have messed up somewhere.  I can't even reproduce it now. If I figure out what went wrong, I'll report back. But for now, thank you so much for your help. I have deleted my comment above since it's likely incorrect. Thanks akrun!

Comment: @PatrickT if you want to find why it is returning the first element.  check the source code of `base::setdiff`, where `x` and `y` are converted to `vector` with `as.vector`, but it won't work with `list` i.e. it needs `unlist` which is not happening i.e. `x <- as.vector(x);
    y <- as.vector(y);`  and using an example `as.vector(list(1:3))#
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3` and the match step returns TRUE and thus it gives the first element `as.vector(list(1:3))[match(as.vector(list(1:3)), as.vector(list(3:5)), 0L) == 0L]
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3`

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying, I get it! Thanks!